# Applying mask for an input field for date in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, meiomask

I am using `jquery.meio.mask` to format a date in a textbox which is having datepicker attached to it. Everything is working fine except that when the user manually enters a date after he enters the 3rd digit (after the first /) the cursor is coming infront of the 3rd digit and when he enters the 4th digit it is replacing the 3rd digit he entered which results in missing one digit every time. I am setting the mask to the text field using the below code,

```
$('#txtFrom,#txtTo' ).focus(function() {
              $( this ).setMask({
                    mask : '19/39/2999'
                });
});
```

I am new to Jquery. Could some one help me how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try To implement This way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    dateMask($('#txtFrom'));
    dateMask($('#txtTo'));
});
function dateMask(element)
{
    $( element ).setMask({
         mask : '19/39/2999'
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing as above...but it is behaving in the same way :(